# How can I update RCurl to use sftp?

Tags: curl, sas, sftp, rcurl

I am using the RCurl package in RCloud to transfer file from RCloud to SAS. Unfortunately, the underling curl function currently doesn't support SFTP. 
When I run:

`curlVersion()$protocols`

That's what I get:

```
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"

 [9] "imaps"  "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtsp"   "smb"    "smbs"   "smtp"   "smtps" 

 [17] "telnet" "tftp"
```

Any idea how I can update RCurl to include sftp?

Comment: Glad to hear you are using RCloud but this question doesn't have anything to do with RCloud, just RCurl. I found this near-duplicate but it doesn't look like the answer is complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411969/sftp-with-r-sftp-not-a-protocol-with-rcurl