# curl: (1) Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: curl, cmd

I can currently connect to an ssh server using the GUI software WinSCP, but would like to connect via shell from now on. I have the direct URL/Username/Password that is needed to connect via port 22. There is not a key that is needed at this time. I have tried the following commands unsuccessfully:

```
curl  -k "sftp://test.com" --user "USERNAME:PASSWORD" -T "C:\file\test.zip" --ftp-create-dirs
```

This is the error that I received:

> curl: (1) Protocol "sftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

How do I connect to port 22 via shell with a username/password?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: with proper ssh keys setup, you can do `scp /local/path/to/file user@host:/remote/path/`. Good luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sftp with R - sftp not a protocol with RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411969/sftp-with-r-sftp-not-a-protocol-with-rcurl)

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to do this process in Jenkins - do you know if Jenkins support libssh2? If not, then I have to find another way to reach SFTP